# Do I need to apply for a Korean visa?

Tags: japan, south-korea, filipino-citizens

I am a Philippines passport holder with a permanent visa in Japan. I want to go to South Korea for a 2-3-day tour. Do I need to apply for a Korean tourist visa?

Comment: North or South Korea?

Comment: If somewhere else is your final destination then no you don't need a visa. If you are just going to Korea then back to Japan you need a visa. If you have a visa (study permit, work permit, permanent residency, etc.) from Japan you can transit through & stay in Korea for 30 days, but Korea may NOT be your final destination. http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/OO/OO_EN_13_3_3.jsp

Comment: @BritishSam please don't answer in the comments...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the question was on hold when I answered hence it in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of [Emirates web site sharing of the Timatic tool](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx), the information used by airlines for passenger entry requirements, you would require a visa [(Philippine passport holder, living in Japan)](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PH&NV=Philippines&AC=JP&AV=Japan&DC=KR&DV=Korea%2c+Republic+of&h=ff14bee786d7f8ae37d1fa511740b952a7c411):

> **Destination - Korea, Republic of (KR)**
>
> **Passport**
>   Passport required.
>   **Passport Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Philippines with an emergency passport.
>   **Document Validity:**
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on arrival.
>   **Warning:**
>   Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card must travel with a passport. The passport number and nationality must match those stated on the card.
>   **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>   **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Philippines with a visa issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom if in transit through Korea (Rep.) must: 
>   - hold confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when
>   -arriving from the country that issued the visa and departing to a third country. (YVR-ICN-DEL); or
>   -arriving from a third country and departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or
>   -arriving from a third country after having transited that country for a maximum stay of 3 days, departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-SGN-ICN-YVR); or
>   -arriving from a third country, traveling to another country and staying there for a maximum stay of 3 days, then departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-SGN-YVR).
>
> Nationals of Philippines with an e-visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand or USA if in transit through Korea (Rep.) must: 
>   -hold confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when
>   -arriving from the country that issued the visa and departing to a third country.
>
> Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card valid for travel to "KOR" for a maximum stay of 90 days. The card is valid for the countries listed on the back of the card.
>
> **Additional Information:**
>   Nationals of Philippines traveling as a group on business or as a group of school children can be issued with a Group Visa.
>   Holders of e-visas are required to hold an Electronic Visa Issuance Confirmation, issued by the Ministry of Justice.
>
> **Warning:**
>   Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.